# Effusion Flux according to Kinetic Theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

We know from Kinetic Theory that, for a dilute monoatomic gas, particle average velocity perpendicular to a wall of the container is given by:

$$
\begin{align}
\langle v \rangle _s &= \frac{\int_0^\infty v^3 f_M(v) dv \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin \theta \cos \theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi}{ \int_0^\infty v^2 f_M(v) dv \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin \theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi}  \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{2k_B T}{\pi m}}
\end{align}
$$

Where $f_M(v)$ is Maxwell distribution.

Now consider there is a hole in the container, and I want to compute particle effusion flux out of the container to the vacuum $\Phi_e$. On physical grounds we know that:

$$
\langle v \rangle_e > \langle v \rangle_s
$$

Because particles with a higher speed, normal to the hole, have a higher probability to pass through it.

But I cannot derive any explicit equation for effusion flux $\Phi_e$.
If you have any ideas about angular dependence or anything else please let me know.